# Is it okay to integrate database migration tools like Flyway, Liquibase with the application code base?

Tags: java, gradle, database-migration, liquibase, flyway

I mean is it good practice to allow application to modify the db? Or should database migration be done externally to the application code base?

New to this, so any input will be appreciated.

We are using java and gradle to build the application.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? keeping track of migration scripts? or performing the migration?

Comment: Both actually. Prior to this we used to keep separate folder in CVS especially for db scripts. Separate from the code base.

Comment: 'Both, actually'.. the migration is not part of your application, and I don't see any way how your application can perform it. but keeping your migration scripts with your project is logical: how will you later on install your appliction somewhere if you don't know how to build the DB?

Comment: I think there are few gradle flyway plugins  which gives you tasks to migrate. Not sure about liquibase or others though.

Comment: so, you want your db migration to be done by an application that might not be able to start up correctly unless the migration has been done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) author here.

Yes! At the end of the day, there are two important forces at play:

1. **Your schema is really tightly coupled to your application code**: Your application expects certain tables and columns to be present so it can read & write to them. Which ones exactly varies from one release of your application to the next.
2. **You don't want to do database-based integration between applications/services** as this breaks all encapsulation. A database is a private implementation detail of a service. Integration with other services should happen via an API layer with proper validation and business rules enforcement.

And so in light of all this, just **keep together what belongs together**.

By letting the application [**migrate the database on startup**](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/), you ensure the database schema is always in sync with the application's expectations of what it should find there.

Comment: Can flyway generate the update schema instead of directly running against the DB. In some cased DBA's might want to have a look at the scripts before executing them on the production dbs.

Comment: Production is way too late for this. Have your DBAs collaborate with dev so you have the correct changes applied to ALL databases (dev, test, staging & prod!).

Comment: Ideally the DBA would collaborate with dev so changes would be pre-approved, but the reality is that some organisations have hard-to-change established processes that requires a script to be reviewed. Axel - maybe this is value add we could add to FlySQL? ;) @anything - Please contact me at David dot Atkinson at Red-gate dot com as I'd like to understand your requirements in more detail!

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Axel on keeping this together.

However, when your DB user doesn't have the rights to change the DB structure or your simply not supposed to change the structure it comes in handy to not let the tool run the structure changes directly but generate SQL scripts instead.

These can then be given to a DB admin who inspects and approves the SQLs first and then runs those himself.

This is how we (have to) do it.

Don't get mistaken. This is just one level of indirection more. Instead of letting the tool execute the SQL directly you let the tool write the SQL to a file. And then the DBA will execute the SQL from the file.

Comment: I would support this anwer. I have been in many projects where, for security reasons, the database user of the application has no DDL rights. And I would argue this is pretty common. Your solution definitly works, I just wanted to show how we do it in our company. Here, these steps are fully automated. We are extracting the Flyway/Liquibase scripts (part of the project) in our build as an additional artifact (project-migrations.zip) besides the application itself. During deployment our orchestration tool simply executes  these scripts with DBA rights and afterwards deploys the application.

Answer (score 0):

Not, unless you are not aware of:

- you have multiple applications running in the same database. So, you need to choose one which will be holding all scripts.
- you need to be able to rollback your deployment, otherwise you need to snapshot DB on every startup.
- your DBA providing to your application ability to perform schema alteration, i.e. doing schema change without their approvals.

Coupling code and schema easily achieved by holding flyway target version with the code in all your projects.